# Constraint line is not working in design view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Please click on this link for the image:
[image: Please click on this link for the image]

Second image for new project:
[image: Second image for new project]

Please see Image above. I have added many button/view to the layout. But there is no constraint line/ alignment line that I used to see when I add new items to the layout. Also, I don't see my view/button show up in the design view.

What is wrong? How can I fix this. So, I can design my layout quickly in the design view?

One note, when I create the first app project. I suppose to see the word "Hello world" in the middle, but I didn't see it this time also

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild your project then you will be able to see it, the problem occurred because your code contained some error when it was building so building failed and android studio don't show preview if that happens.

Cleaning and rebuilding will solve your problem

Comment: I tried to create a new project to test this scenario, but it does not work. I uninstalled android studio, and download the new one and it re-install it, but does not work also

Comment: When you created a new project at that time textview was in the view or not

Comment: From the picture you uploaded you can see that there occurred an error so rendering failed, in menu click on build, then clean, then click on rebuild

Comment: when I create a new project, I don't even see the hello world in the middle with 4 constraint lines, which I usually see. I then added couple buttons, but there is no alignment line when I drag onto the layout. When I drop, there is no constraint line. I didn't not touch anything else beside changing the "hello world" to different words

Comment: I just tried to run it on my physical device, I saw the "hello world" in the middle of my device. I look at the design, that hello world is not working there. So frustrated.

Comment: I have added another image, just right after I create the new project. The "hello world" is not show up

Comment: I tried "From the picture you uploaded you can see that there occurred an error so rendering failed, in menu click on build, then clean, then click on rebuild". And it is not working